# how to dynamically give names to buttons using a listbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
Dim cont = 0
    If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then

        For i =1 To ListBox1.Items.Count
            Dim botao3 As New Button

            botao3.Text = CStr(ListBox2.Items(cont)) 'table.Item(i).text & 
            botao3.BringToFront()
            botao3.Top = top
            botao3.Left = 40
            botao3.Width = 300

            Me.Controls.Add(botao3)

            top = top + 30

            cont = cont + 1
        Next

    End If
```

ps. my listbox has the sorted propriety set to true

this its my code but it will only give it the name of the last inserted value on the listbox .

how can i make this so that when ever i click the button it deletes the old set of buttons and add a new set of button the one i have just inserted.

and please give me a hand :$

Comment: why do you have listbox1 and listbox2? you iterate on listbox1 items but you use the index on listbox2 items

Comment: And btw, you don't need `cont` there... you have `i`

Answer (score 0):

You put `0` instead of the current loop value

```
botao3.Text = CStr(ListBox2.Items(0))
```

should be

```
botao3.Text = CStr(ListBox2.Items(i))
```

For the other part, I am not sure what you want to achieve but you can have `Me.Controls.Clear()` before your loop.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
  Dim btn As Button() = New Button(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            btn(i) = New Button()
            btn(i).Text = ListBox1.Items(i).ToString()
            If i > 0 Then
                btn(i).Left = btn(i - 1).Right
            End If

            Me.Controls.Add(btn(i))
        Next
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then

    For i =0 To ListBox1.Items.Count
        Dim botao3 As New Button

        botao3.Text = CStr(ListBox1.Items(i)) 'table.Item(i).text & 
        botao3.BringToFront()
        botao3.Top = top
        botao3.Left = 40
        botao3.Width = 300

        Me.Controls.Add(botao3)

        top = top + 30
    Next

End If
```